# How to sync all my Exchange files (including Notes and Tasks) to my Nexus S?

Tags: sync, 2.3-gingerbread, samsung-nexus-s, exchange, notes

I need to find a way to sync my Outlook notes and tasks to my Nexus S.

I would also like to have all the fields I use in my contacts in Outlook available in my Nexus S.

I rund on Exchange and the mail, contacts, and calendar syncronize OK with my Nexus S, though some fields are not available in Gingerbread and can't decide how long back I want my appointmens and emails to sync...

Answer (score 1):

Try [NitroNote](http://groups.google.com/group/nitrodesk/web/nitronote-notes-syncing?hl=en&pli=1) - it offers syncing for Outlook Notes. You'll need to install apps on your desktop as well as the device.

There's also the more powerful [TouchDown](http://www.nitrodesk.com/dk_touchdownFeatures.aspx) client which will sync email / contacts / tasks from an Exchange server.

Finally, lots of users claim to find [gSyncit](http://www.daveswebsite.com/software/gsync/) to work well for them, but YMMV.